# Data not appearing in Shopping Analysis

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I am using Enhanced Ecommerce to monitor events of a step-by-step checkout process.

Note: Triple confirmed that EC is enabled on the Analytics Property, and Checkout Funnel Labels have been set (albeit the latter being not required anyway)

When a user clicks the "Next step" button on step 1, the following code gets fired:

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {step: 1});
ga(
    'send',
    'event',
    'Checkout',
    'Customer Proceeding to Select Accomodation'
)
```

This event appears in `Real-Time > Events`:

[image: How it appears in GA]

..but won't appear in `Conversions > Ecommerce > Shopping Analysis > Checkout Behavior`

I can't find where I'm going wrong to save my life here so any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: how long did you wait?

Comment: Mid-development of a huge system and I first started sending events through about 3 weeks ago and got distracted with another particular. Now i'm back on this and still nothing. So 3weeks 1 day.

Comment: Opened a bounty, still not getting anything in Shopping Analysis despite events being sent hundreds of times per day under the 'checkout' category and appearing in events

Comment: @Zanderwar did you try the suggestions from my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue I see is ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {**'step'**: 1});
( Put step in quotes )

Still the issue can persist and this is a general checklist for implementing the Shopping Behaviour analytics.

- In your Google Analytics tracking code, the enhanced ecommerce plugin should be included.  ga(‘require’, ‘ec’);
- To ensure the data flows into the Shopping Behaviour report, you need to send all of the ec:setAction steps. It's important to send these events and in the right order, I have also suggested when you should do that in comments but that's upto you.

```js
ga(‘ec:setAction’, ‘detail’);
 //Set this parameter when a visitor views a Product Detail page.

ga(‘ec:setAction’, ‘add’);
//Set this parameter when a visitor adds a product to their cart.   

ga(‘ec:setAction’, ‘checkout’);
//Set this parameter when a visitor views the checkout process pages. 

ga(‘ec:setAction’, ‘purchase’);
//Set this parameter when a visitor views an Order Confirmation page.
```

- While implementing the shopping analysis steps as mentioned above, do check all the required parameters are set.
- The steps (corresponding to step number for checkout) should defined in the Admin section of Google Analytics (which I guess you already did)